# Android Studio: Error when trying to run App, Supply_width attribute on line 0?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I can't seem to figure out why my application won't run...I've tried to invalidate and restart, rebuild project, and apply layout widths to everything, but it still doesn't work. Is there something to fix the issue? I'm really confused by the layout_width attribute at line 0 problem, couldn't figure it out so far.

Logcat:

```
01-30 21:53:01.964 4622-4622/test.pkg.miclass.decode E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: test.pkg.miclass.decode, PID: 4622
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.pkg.miclass.decode/test.pkg.miclass.decode.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binary XML file line #0: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
                                                                          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:775)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:7554)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7746)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1976)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1874)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1872)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                          at test.pkg.miclass.decode.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

This is the xml I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="383dp"
    android:layout_height="510dp"
    tools:context="test.pkg.miclass.decode.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="363dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Text:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="75dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="KeyPhrase:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/keyphrase"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="136dp">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/encryptGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:gravity="center">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/encrypt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Encrypt" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/decrypt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                tools:text="Decrypt" />
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="207dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/runButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Run" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="285dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Results:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In View

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/runButton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Run" />
```

You add line `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Example:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/runButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Run" />
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It's able to run now. Just curious, why does it give me an error message indicating the problem at line 0, because I definitely overlooked it when I was trying to figure out what was the cause of the issue

Comment: @JoeJ: Binary XML file line #0. Mean file auto gen from your file xml. if your file xml error => file not gen.

Answer (score 1):

Assign Width to the Button-:

Add this line-:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"

<Button
            android:id="@+id/runButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Run" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you declare two TextView with same id  android:id="@+id/textView2"

and

```
 <Button
                android:id="@+id/runButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Run"/>
```